# raise_application_error of -4091 is out of range on UTL_SMTP.quit

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am getting  ORA-21000: error number argument to raise_application_error of -4091 is out of range on UTL_SMTP.quit(connection);

I have SMTP related code in a procedure. so when I run below procedure it works fine. But when i call Send_Mail from a trigger in my application, it's throwing above mentioned error.

```
BEGIN
   Send_Mail (p_to             => 'temp@temp.com',
              p_from           => 'temp@temp.com',
              p_message        => 'Test message',
              p_smtp_host      => 'tempserver'
             );
END;
/
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/errors.htm#i1863) :

**Defining Your Own Error Messages (RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR Procedure)**

The RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR procedure lets you issue user-defined ORA-n error messages from stored subprograms. That way, you can report errors to your application and avoid returning unhandled exceptions.

To invoke RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR, use the following syntax:

raise_application_error(
      error_number, message[, {TRUE | FALSE}]);
where error_number is a **negative integer in the range -20000..-20999** and message is a character string up to 2048 bytes long. If the optional third parameter is TRUE, the error is placed on the stack of previous errors.